# Numbering based on formula

Tags: if-statement, lookup, countif, serial-number

I want to display Sl. No. in a column based on a flag field in another column.

If flag is “m”, then the Sl. No corresponding to that item is incremented by 1
If flag is “s”, then the Sl. No is corresponding to that item is indicated as main item number + 0.01
If "h" is encountered, numbering should be restarted.

Presently, I have used `=IF(B3="","",IF(B3="m",COUNTIF($B$2:B3,"m"),LOOKUP(10^35,$D$1:D2)+0.01))` in Cell `D3`. 

 The formula delivers the sequence of numbering as desired. But, the numbering does not restart *(see Cell `D17` in image below where it should have been 1.00 instead of 4.00*). 
***Note:*** As per my requirement, there are blank rows between the rows of "Flag" field as shown.

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 0):

I used the following formula in Cell `C3` `=IF(B3="h",0,IF(B3="m",INT(SUM(C2,1)),IF(B3="s",SUM(C2,0.01),IF(OR(B3="",B3="tot"),C2))))`

It restarts the numbering of items and sub-items whenever “h” is encountered.